# How to merge two files in corresponding row?

Tags: shell, text-processing, paste

Now,I have two files:

`aaaa.txt`:

```
a=0;
b=1;
c=2;
```

`bbbb.txt`:

```
d=3
e=4
f=5
```

I want to merge `aaaa.txt` and `bbbb.txt` to `cccc.txt`.

`cccc.txt` as follow:

```
a=0;d=3
b=1;e=4
c=2;f=5
```

So, what can I do for this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use paste for this:

```
paste -d '\0' aaaa.txt bbbb.txt > cccc.txt
```

From your question, it appears that the first file contains `;` at the end. If it didn't, you could use that as the delimiter by using `-d ';'` instead.

Note that contrary to what one may think, with `-d '\0'`, it's not pasting with a NUL character as the delimiter, but with an empty delimiter. That is the standard way to specify an empty delimiter. Some `paste` implementations like GNU `paste` allow `paste -d ''` for that, but it's neither standard nor portable (many other implementations will report an error about the missing delimiter if you use `paste -d ''`).

Comment: @ Chris Down - Thank you very much, it working.By the way, another question: awk '{ sed 's/.*,/999/g' }' cccc.txt why it return awk: { sed s/.*,/999/g } awk: ^ syntax error. What's wrong with it?

Comment: I'm not totally sure what you're trying to do, but you can't just pass sed to awk like that...

Comment: @ Chris Down - Thans,I get it.

Comment: Please ask separate questions as, well, separate questions. It makes them useful for later users (possible to find!).